# Is it possible to add attachments to iCloud reminders?

Tags: reminders

I can add links to the Notes field of Reminders - but I don't seem to be able to drag files into there. Is there a way to link to a PDF on iCloud Drive perhaps?

Comment: Just to clarify - this is for the Reminders app for macOS and iOS not the Notes app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of today, it's not possible to add attachments to a Reminder in [either macOS or iOS](https://9to5mac.com/2018/06/17/apples-reminders-app-needs-five-additional-features-to-be-a-true-task-manager/).

I've read that some people have used 3rd-party apps (like Fantastical) to manage their reminders.  Doing that gives them additional features not found in Apple Reminders app.  I can't speak to that because I haven't tried those apps but you might want to look into that if this an important feature to you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102484), in iOS 13 or later, to add an attachment, "Tap the Photos buttonNo alt supplied for Image to add an attachment to the reminder. You can take a new photo, choose an image from your photo library, or scan a document."